# Access to media devices using VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a project using Vue.js and i would like to take a picture using device camera, i did that using native Javascript, but i couldn't in VueJs, webpack give me some error like with await for example:

can someone help me to write that in VueJs

This is my code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="video-wrap">
        <video id="video" playsinline autoplay></video>
    </div>

    <div class="controller">
        <button id="snap">snap</button>
    </div>

    <canvas id="canvas" height="200" width="200"></canvas>

    <script>
        'use strict';
        const video = document.getElementById('video');
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const snap = document.getElementById('snap');
        const errorMsgElement = document.getElementById('spanErrorMsg');

        const browserAPI = {
            audio: true,
            video: {
                width: 200,
                height:200,

            }
        }

        async function init(){
            try{
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(browserAPI);
                handleSuccess(stream);
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log(e)
            }
        }

        function handleSuccess(stream){
            window.stream = stream;
            video.srcObject = stream;
        }

        init();

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        snap.addEventListener('click', function(){
            context.drawImage(video, 0,0, 200, 200);
        })

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My VUE JS Code :

```
export default {
components:{Modal},
data: () => ({
    showModal: false,
    form: {
        BusinessCard: '',
    },
    created() {
        const video = document.getElementById('video');
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const snap = document.getElementById('snap');
        const errorMsgElement = document.getElementById('spanErrorMsg');

        const browserAPI = {
        audio: true,
        video: {
            width: 200,
            height:200,
            }
        }
        try{
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(browserAPI);
                handleSuccess(stream);
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        capture(){
            
        },
        extractData(){

        }
    }
}),
  }
```

Can you help me to continue  my code in VueJS

Answer (score 1):

To use `await`, it must be wrapped in an `async` function.

In your case, make `created` async:

```js
export default {
    async created() {
        //...
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(browserAPI);
    },
}
```

Also, not sure if this is a typo, but your code shows `data()` wrapping the `created` hook and `methods`, but those should be at the root of the component options.

Comment: Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing some "bracket" after `data` function and if you want to use await in `created` function you need to add async in front of function name.

try this code

```
export default {
  components: { Modal },
  data: () => ({
    showModal: false,
    form: {
      BusinessCard: "",
    },
  }),
  async created() {
    const video = document.getElementById("video");
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const snap = document.getElementById("snap");
    const errorMsgElement = document.getElementById("spanErrorMsg");

    const browserAPI = {
      audio: true,
      video: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
      },
    };
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(browserAPI);
      handleSuccess(stream);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    capture() {},
    extractData() {},
  },
};
```